# R: add letter to sequence in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, addition, sequence

I have a dataframe like below and i want to add 4 letter (CATG) in front of the sequences. Is that possible? Thank you All!

```
   test<-as.data.frame("ACTCAATAAACATAGCT",
   "TTTGACAGTATTGTTTG", 
   "CTTTTCAAGAGTGATGG",
   "GCGACTCCCATCAGTGA", 
   "GCCAGCCACACATCAGG", 
   "TTTATTTAAGAGGAAGA", 
   "GTCTGAAGAATTGTTCA", 
   "ATTCTGATACTAATATA",
   "CTCCACGTCCACCCCAA", 
   "GGGAAGTCTGCCCTGCT")
```

This should be the result!

```
   CATGACTCAATAAACATAGCT
   CATGTTTGACAGTATTGTTTG 
   CATGCTTTTCAAGAGTGATGG
   CATGGCGACTCCCATCAGTGA 
   CATGGCCAGCCACACATCAGG 
   CATGTTTATTTAAGAGGAAGA 
   CATGGTCTGAAGAATTGTTCA 
   CATGATTCTGATACTAATATA
   CATGCTCCACGTCCACCCCAA 
   CATGGGGAAGTCTGCCCTGCT
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test<-data.frame(V1=c("ACTCAATAAACATAGCT",
   "TTTGACAGTATTGTTTG", 
   "CTTTTCAAGAGTGATGG",
   "GCGACTCCCATCAGTGA", 
   "GCCAGCCACACATCAGG", 
   "TTTATTTAAGAGGAAGA", 
   "GTCTGAAGAATTGTTCA", 
   "ATTCTGATACTAATATA",
   "CTCCACGTCCACCCCAA", 
   "GGGAAGTCTGCCCTGCT"))
> test$V1<-paste0('CATG',test$V1)
> test
                      V1
1  CATGACTCAATAAACATAGCT
2  CATGTTTGACAGTATTGTTTG
3  CATGCTTTTCAAGAGTGATGG
4  CATGGCGACTCCCATCAGTGA
5  CATGGCCAGCCACACATCAGG
6  CATGTTTATTTAAGAGGAAGA
7  CATGGTCTGAAGAATTGTTCA
8  CATGATTCTGATACTAATATA
9  CATGCTCCACGTCCACCCCAA
10 CATGGGGAAGTCTGCCCTGCT
```

Comment: thanks to ttmaccer! the only suggestion is to add this: sep=""